# STK 11.2: perform a low-thrust optimal transfer

Tags: orbital-maneuver, stk-agi, low-thrust

I'm using **STK 11.2** to find a minimum-time finite transfer between two coplanar orbits. The first orbit is circular and has a `radius 7000km`, the second orbit has a `semimajor axis = 10000km` and `eccentricity = 0.1`.

For the optimization I use `Design Explorer Optimizer` (in this version there is no SNOPT or IPOPT). Unfortunately, the solution doesn't converge.

What is wrong in my configuration?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: different question but somewhat related and of interest to future readers: [Software for low-thrust trajectory optimization](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46522/12102)

Comment: First you should move the first propagate out of the TargetSequence. There is nothing to optimize. Second: why to you have a duration as a target? I think you can remove this to.

Comment: @CallMeTom The first propagate is in the Target sequence because I want to find the optimal True anomaly to start the maneuver. Duration is a target because I want to minimize it.

Comment: @Leeloo: since you have not specified the target AoP and you start on a circular orbit, there is nothing like an optimal true anomaly? (execpt the numerical error produces a pseudo one)

Comment: @CallMeTom Well, I've changed this. However, this doesn't affect the convergence.

Comment: @Leeloo, i quite sure, there is not one probem, but several. The AoP one was for sure. The next I would recommend to try changing the Maneuver Type to "impulsive". Look if it converge then. My experiance is, that non-impulsive manuevers always struggle to converge. First when the sequence is stable enough to converge with an impulsive maneuver try to make it more realistic

Comment: if/when it converge, try a engine with more thrust at first, and try to reduce the thrust step by step till you reach your wanted thrust ... the sequence will also not converg, if the thrust is to low to reach your goal with one burn

Comment: @CallMeTom If you have an STK, may I ask you to publish an answer?

Comment: I am ready to help you with experience I have and to point errors you made and I found. But I fear you will have to work out the answer by yourself, at least I am not ready to spent time on working out the whole scenario for you. Another topic, why this sequence may not converge: if you apply thurst and reach the target SMA, it is not given, that the ecc will be correct. So after raising your apo you would need a second burn to make the peri fit.

Comment: @CallMeTom I changed the maneuver type to impulsive, the thrust increased to 1000 N, as the control used the cartesian components of velocity. It hasn't converge either (in several iterations it stops).

Comment: @CallMeTom May be I should use Differential Corrector first?

Comment: @Leeloo: yes! try the DC first. In general start with a very easy sequence and if/when it converge make it step by step more complicated.

Comment: @CallMeTom Tried, the same thing, it doesn't converge. I've added a bounty for this question.

Comment: are you still trying to reach an orbit AND eccentricity?

Comment: @CallMeTom I checked them separately, in my case even semi-major axes doesn't converge.

Comment: okey ... so to sum up, you have a circular orbit ,one impulsive maneuver and a new SMA.. and this does not converge?? strange... ehh, do you still have the propagate element before the sequence? I said you need to move it out, but does it has an abort criteria?

Comment: @CallMeTom Yes, I checked your suggestions and it doesn't still converge. If you have an STK, it would be great if you check and publish a solution.

Comment: since i do not have an Astrogator license on my private comupter and since this is nothing I can do just quick during the lunch break, I am afraid I cannot help you with a ready to use solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell from the parameters in your screenshots, the program has performed a perfectly valid optimisation.

What's more concerning is that the text in you question doesn't match the parameters clearly shown in the screenshots. If there's a configuration page where does values are actually used, why is this not included in the question?

The optimiser has been tasked to achieve these constraints:

- Obtain a semi-major axis between 8000km and 8010km. The value it reached, 7999.57km, is within the tolerances you have specified. The values here are **not** the 10000km you claim in the question.
- Achieve an eccentricity between 0 and 0.01. The value it reached is 0.00068, safely within. This is **not** your claimed input of 0.1

Given those two constraints, which has been met, it has minimised the time to a journey under 24 days.

The second concerning thing is the notice about "stop after specified duration". Since the value there is the exact same as what the optimiser output, is it perhaps the case that the provided time is not enough to reach the target orbit? 24 days is not a very long time as far as low-thrust transfers are concerned.

[image: parameters]

Comment: I dind't catch the second concerning thing. "stop after specified duration" is a control.