# Is there a basic 2 or 3 body space simulator

Tags: orbital-mechanics, simulator

I would like an educational tool to allow a child to 'drag and drop' or 'add' a planet to a workspace, adjust the x, y and z velocities as well as the size and mass.

OF the numerous simulators I have looked at, the complexity is daunting and the cognitive load may be too great for an average middle schooler.

I read this post

[Can Kerbal Space Program act as a suitable simulator with the right mods?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/41722/can-kerbal-space-program-act-as-a-suitable-simulator-with-the-right-mods)

and the suggestions are nice but quite complex.

I read this post

[Game for teaching basics of orbital mechanics](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32776/game-for-teaching-basics-of-orbital-mechanics)

but even these suggestions are beyond the simple ideas I would like to present in a simple talk that cannot exceed 1 class.(45 minutes)

Osmos is close but I need something that shows numbers (velocities, masses, acceleration)

Something like Kerbal would be nice but even simpler. Say I want to put a couple of bowling balls in space and adjust their mass and velocities so they orbit. Or perhaps put them in space and examine elastic collisions.

Comment: Are you searching for a free tool or are you willing to pay? The reason that I am asking is that I think a 2D variant could be rather easy to program and thus cheap to commission.

Comment: You could ask the computer science department at some university for a colabotation. Creating things like this is the type of things students do for practice. At least where I was studying (Umeå University - Sweden)

Comment: Are you aware of the "3-body problem" ? Any system you set up with 3 or more bodies of reasonably comparable mass will be chaotic & unrepeatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Universe Sandbox](http://universesandbox.com/) is probably what you want. Great tool, drag and drop, add in objects where you desire, etc. Orbits all figured in. There's a ton of stuff you can do with it, I've used it in a few videos to explain supernovas and stuff like that, but it works well for orbital mechanics too.

Comment: pretty good but too much distraction with pretty pictures - but maybe that's a plus

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Space Engine](http://spaceengine.org/)? It might be complex as well but I think this could work.

Comment: thank but it is quite complex. something like this      https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/gravity-and-orbits      but more customizable in terms of celestial body mass,size and velocity

Comment: so far i struggle with this     https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/legacy/my-solar-system